# Sum all the class attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, attributes

I have a class like this one: (The name of the class: Man)

> Name:"daniel" | numOfLegs: 5 | numOfHands: 7 | numOfEyes: 10 | numofHeads: 80 |
>   numofBrains: 2

I want to sum all the attributes into one int but its very long code:

```
int sum= Man.numOfLegs+Man.numOfHands+Man.numOfEyes+Man.numofHeads+Man.numofBrains;
```

The problem is that I have more than 80 attributes and it keeps growing.

Help me please :(

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with reflection. I do not know if this is the best way. If you consider this class:

```
public class Man
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could sum them like this:

```
var man=new Man(){Bar=12,Foo=21};
var total= man.GetType()
    .GetProperties()
    .Where(w =>w.PropertyType==typeof(int))
    .Sum (s=>(int)s.GetValue(man,null));
```

The total will be all the int fields in the class

**Edit**

If you have a list. You could do this:

```
var ls=new List<Man>();
ls.Add(new Man(){Bar=12,Foo=21});
var total= ls.Sum(man => man.GetType()
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(w =>w.PropertyType==typeof(int))
        .Sum (s=>(int)s.GetValue(man,null)))
```

Comment: And if i want to put the attributes in a list? Thanks for your help :)